# How to get an uniform location of a Cg shader with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, shader, uniform, cg

I've dabbled with basic shader programming before, using the GLSL way. Now I've come back to it, using Cg shaders. Following the tutorial at [Josh Beam's website](http://joshbeam.com/articles/cg_pixel_shaders_in_opengl/) I've achieved the desired functionality, was able to change my shader around, however I couldn't manipulate the uniforms in it on the OpenGL side.

```
GLuint handle;
::glGenProgramsARB(1, &handle);
::glBindProgramARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, handle);
::glProgramStringARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, GL_PROGRAM_FORMAT_ASCII_ARB, strlen(pSource), pSource);

while(true)
{
  ::glEnable(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB);
  ::glBindProgramARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, handle);
  // render
  ::glDisable(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB);
  // present backbuffer
}
```

Works perfectly. If I try to `::glGetUniformLocationARB(handle, pUniformName)`, I get a GL_INVALID_VALUE error. Tried to do this both after creating the shader, and after binding, to the same outcome. I have also tried to `::glUseProgramObjectARB(handle)`, as different sources suggested, however this didn't work either, and seems to belong to the GLSL way ([Lighthouse3D tutorials](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/)).

I have double-checked that the uniform name is correct.

I have also found an approach ([NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/cg_vertex_shader/25002/)), that involves #include-ing Cg headers and calling cg APIs. Is this not doable using OpenGL API-s? (The reason for this is minimalism; I want to make this functionality a part of a static library, and I'm all for minimising the number of compiling / linking dependencies.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing different extensions.

The term "uniform" refers to GLSL global variables declared with the `uniform` keyword. ARB assembly shaders do not have uniforms. They have a similar concept, but they don't call them "uniforms". `glGetUniformLocationARB` is a GLSL function. The [ARB assembly](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_program.txt) term for them is "program local parameter". These are naturally set by the `glProgramLocalParameterARB` series of functions.

Oh, and you should never use any GLSL functions that end in ARB. *Ever*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, that's a typo on my part, I'm calling glGenProgramsARB. Editing the original...

Comment: "Oh, and you should never use any GLSL functions that end in ARB. Ever." Because of this? http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Selecting_a_Shading_Language#ARB_assembly

Comment: @iCE-9: Well, _you_ shouldn't do it for what you're doing, because you're using ARB assembly. ARB assembly is not the same thing as the GLSL functions ending in ARB, which come from the extension ARB_shader_objects. *That* extension shouldn't be used by *anyone* because it's old and outdated. GLSL has been core OpenGL for over 6 years; if you're using GLSL, you should use core GLSL. There's no knowing how the old extension-based GLSL functions react to newer shader versions.